# How to add Rows and Delete Rows to calculate again?

Tags: html, jquery

```js
function autoCalcSetup(){
    $('form[name=transactions]').jAutoCalc('destroy');
    $('form[name=transactions] tr[name=services]').jAutoCalc({keyEventsFire: true, decimalPlaces: 2, emptyAsZero: true});
    $('form[name=transactions]').jAutoCalc({decimalPlaces: 2});
}

autoCalcSetup();

$('button[name=remove]').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var form = $(this).parents('form')

    $(this).parents('tr').remove();
    autoCalcSetup();
});

$('button[name=add]').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var $table = $(this).parents('table');
    var $top = $table.find('tr[name=services]').first();
    var $new = $top.clone(true);
    
    $new.jAutoCalc('destroy');
    $new.insertBefore($top);
    $new.find('input[type=text]').val('');

    autoCalcSetup();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">


<!-- blank.html  21 Nov 2019 03:54:41 GMT -->
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" name="viewport">
  <title>I-MED HEALTHCARE</title>
  <!-- General CSS Files -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/app.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bundles/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bundles/bootstrap-colorpicker/dist/css/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bundles/select2/dist/css/select2.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bundles/jquery-selectric/selectric.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bundles/bootstrap-timepicker/css/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bundles/datatables/datatables.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bundles/datatables/DataTables-1.10.16/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jautocalc@1.3.1/dist/jautocalc.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Template CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/components.css">

  <!-- Custom style CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/custom.css">
  <link rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon' href='assets/img/imed.png' />

</head>

<body>
  <div class="loader"></div>
    <div id="app">
      <div class="main-wrapper main-wrapper-1">
        <div class="navbar-bg"></div>
      
        <!-- top bar  -->
        <?php require_once("include/topbar.php");  ?>
        <!-- top bar -->

        
        <!-- side bar  -->
        <?php require_once("include/sidebar.php");  ?>
        <!-- side bar -->

        <!-- Main Content -->
        <div class="main-content">
          <section class="section">
            <div class="section-body">
              <!-- add content here -->
              <div class="row">
                  
                <div class="col-12">
                  <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                      <h3>Patient Transactions</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal"
                        data-target=".bd-example-modal-xl">Find Patient</button>
                      </div>
                      <div class="container">
                        <form name="transactions">
                          <table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped" name="transactions">
                            <thead>
                              <tr>
                                <th></th>
                                <th>Item</th>
                                <th>Quantity</th>
                                <th>Price</th>
                                <th>Item Total</th>
                              </tr>        
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                              <tr name="services">
                                <td><button class="btn btn-primary" name="remove">Remove</button></td>
                                <td>Stuff</td>
                                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="qty" value="3"></td>
                                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="price" value="12"></td>
                                <td><input type="text" style="text-align:right" class="form-control" name="item_total" jAutoCalc="{qty} * {price}"></td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td>Subtotal</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td><input type="text" style="text-align:right" class="form-control" name="subtotal" jAutoCalc="SUM({item_total})"></td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td colspan="2"></td>
                                <td>Tax</td>
                                <td>
                                  <select class="form-control" name="tax">
                                    <option value=".06">CT Tax</option>
                                    <option value=".00">Tax Free</option>
                                  </select>
                                </td>
                                <td><input type="text" style="text-align:right" class="form-control" name="tax_total" jAutoCalc="{subtotal} * {tax}"></td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td colspan="2"></td>
                                <td>Total</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td><input type="text" style="text-align:right" class="form-control" name="grand_total" jAutoCalc="{subtotal} + {tax_total}"></td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td colspan="4"></td>
                                <td><button class="btn btn-primary" name="add">Add Row</button></td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </form>
                      </div>
                                              
                      <div class="text-right">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-icon icon-right" name="save"><i class="fas fa-file-invoice"></i> Process Payment</a>
                      </div>

                    </div>      
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </section>        
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>      
  <!-- End of Main Content -->

  <!-- FIND PATIENT TABLE MODAL -->
  <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-xl" id="select-patient"tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel"
  aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="myLargeModalLabel">Find Patient</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="section-body">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-12">
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header">
                    <h4> </h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="table-responsive">

                      <?php
                        require_once("include/connect.php");

                        try{
                            $sql="SELECT patient_id, CONCAT(patient_lname, ', ', patient_fname, ' ', patient_mi) AS Fullname, top, pay_method FROM tbl_patientinfo WHERE isDeleted='0'";
                            $result=$con->prepare($sql);
                            $result->execute();
                      ?>
                
                      <table class="table table-hover" id="table-1">
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th class="text-center">
                              #
                            </th>
                            <th>Patient Name</th>
                            <th>Age</th>
                            <th>Gender</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                          <?php while($row=$result->fetch()){ ?>
                            <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
                              <td><?php echo $row['patient_id']; ?></td>
                              <td><?php echo $row['Fullname']; ?></td>
                              <td><?php echo $row['top']; ?></td>
                              <td><?php echo $row['pay_method']; ?></td>
                            </tr>

                          <?php } ?>

                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                      
                      <?php
                        } catch (PDOException $th){
                          echo "Error: ".$th->getMessage();
                        }

                        $con=null;
                      ?>

                      <script>
                        var table = document.getElementById('table-1');
                        for(var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++)
                        {
                            table.rows[i].onclick = function()
                            {
                                //rIndex = this.rowIndex;
                                document.getElementById("txt-patient_id").value = this.cells[0].innerHTML;
                                document.getElementById("txt-patient_name").value = this.cells[1].innerHTML;
                                document.getElementById("txt-payMethod").value = this.cells[3].innerHTML;
                                $('#select-patient').modal('hide');
                            };                            
                        }
                      </script>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End of FIND PATIENT TABLE MODAL -->

  <!-- setting bar -->
    <?php require_once("include/settingbar.php");  ?>
  <!-- setting bar -->
      
  <!-- footer bar -->
    <?php require_once("include/footer.php");  ?>
  <!-- footer bar -->

  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/bundles/CRUD/transaction.js"></script>
    
  <!-- General JS Scripts -->
  <script src="assets/js/app.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/bundles/datatables/datatables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/bundles/datatables/DataTables-1.10.16/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>

  <!-- JS Libraies -->
  <script src="assets/bundles/cleave-js/dist/cleave.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/bundles/cleave-js/dist/addons/cleave-phone.us.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/bundles/jquery-pwstrength/jquery.pwstrength.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/bundles/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/bundles/bootstrap-colorpicker/dist/js/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/bundles/bootstrap-timepicker/js/bootstrap-timepicker.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/bundles/select2/dist/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/bundles/jquery-selectric/jquery.selectric.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/bundles/sweetalert/sweetalert.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Page Specific JS File -->
  <script src="assets/js/page/forms-advanced-forms.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/page/sweetalert.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/page/datatables.js"></script>

  <!-- Template JS File -->
  <script src="assets/js/scripts.js"></script>
  <!-- Custom JS File -->
  <script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/page/sweetalert.js"></script>

</body>

<!-- blank.html  21 Nov 2019 03:54:41 GMT -->
</html>
```

I have a problem in adding and removing rows. When I type numbers to calculate it using jAutoCalc library, it's working. So I don't have any problem with that. But when I want to add some rows and removing some rows, it shows nothing. And I don't see anything error in my program. But according to Inspects in my Browser (I'm using Microsoft Edge), I have an error in "$new.jAutoCalc('destroy'); " and it says that "$new.jAutoCalc" is not a function.

I use this following codes:

```js
function autoCalcSetup() {
  $('form[name=transactions]').jAutoCalc('destroy');
  $('form[name=transactions] tr[name=services]').jAutoCalc({
    keyEventsFire: true,
    decimalPlaces: 2,
    emptyAsZero: true
  });
  $('form[name=transactions]').jAutoCalc({
    decimalPlaces: 2
  });
}

autoCalcSetup();

$('button[name=remove]').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var form = $(this).parents('form')

  $(this).parents('tr').remove();
  autoCalcSetup();
});

$('button[name=add]').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var $table = $(this).parents('table');
  var $top = $table.find('tr[name=services]').first();
  var $new = $top.clone(true);

  $new.jAutoCalc('destroy'); //this is my error (According to Inspects in Browser)
  $new.insertBefore($top);
  $new.find('input[type=text]').val('');

  autoCalcSetup();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <form name="transactions">
    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped" name="transactions">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>Item</th>
          <th>Quantity</th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <th>Item Total</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr name="services">
          <td><button class="btn btn-primary" name="remove">Remove</button></td>
          <td>Stuff</td>
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="qty" value="3"></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="price" value="12"></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="item_total" jAutoCalc="{qty} * {price}"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>Subtotal</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="subtotal" jAutoCalc="SUM({item_total})"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2"></td>
          <td>Tax</td>
          <td>
            <select class="form-control" name="tax">
              <option value=".06">CT Tax</option>
              <option value=".00">Tax Free</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="tax_total" jAutoCalc="{subtotal} * {tax}"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2"></td>
          <td>Total</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="grand_total" jAutoCalc="{subtotal} + {tax_total}"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4"></td>
          <td><button class="btn btn-primary" name="add">Add Row</button></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>
```

I hope you can help me with this problem. If you have any question please don't hesitate to comment down below, and I will try my best to answer it just to solve my problem here. I need to do this for our Capstone Project. Thank so much! God bless you! :D

Comment: Hi, can you replicate that issue ? Because i am not seeing when i run your code .

Comment: @Swati Hi, I already edited my post. You can run the program on Code Snippet above. Thank you :D

Comment: Hi, sorry for late reply , can you fixed those error message ?

Comment: It's okay. My program right now is working. But thank you Swati 